# How do I change the default XML generated for a blank XPage?

Tags: xpages

The default XML generated when a new XPage is created looks like thi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

</xp:view>
```

but when you add new components from the extension library and other palette items the view xsmlns namespace changes. It also reformats code and screws up any JavaScript and or CSS on the page.

How can I change the default XML created to look more like this and therefore cover my bases when I add new components?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" 
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" 
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

</xp:view>
```

Comment: How would reformatting the XML break inline JS / CSS?

Comment: It places the text arbitrarily on one line and can break functions into lines which don't work. It is also ugly :)

Comment: Ugly aside, I assume you always include semicolons and curlies in all the right spots to avoid having operationally meaningful whitespace. Is that a naive assumption on my part? ;)

Comment: This is hard coded. You can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I could come up with would be to create a template in your Eclipse Designer (Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor > Templates).

Just to test this I created this template:

```
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"  
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
```

Saved it under the name "myAddNamespace" with context "XML Attribute" and "Automatically insert" = ENABLED.

If then I create a new xpage, I can go into source view, place my cursor at the end of the default namespace before the closing '>', then type "my", hit - and then select my template to be inserted at the cursor position:

[image]

I'm aware that this is NOT what you really asked for, but it's at least something

Comment: you're welcome ;) I had long planned to try templating here but never had a proper reason before...

Answer (score 0):

Tested this on 9.0.1 and it automatically formats the way you mention. For example without touching anything I get this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xe:dialog id="dialog1"></xe:dialog>
    <xc:test></xc:test>
</xp:view>
```

You can force a reformat pressing CTRL-SHIFT-F (or right click, source->format). You can modify how the formatting works by selecting "File-Preferences" menu option, then select "XML->XML Files->Editor".

I think what you want is "Split Multiple Attributes each on a new line".

[image]

Comment: thanks Simon - I was not looking for formatting of the code - I only did that for readability. I was wanting to know how to add the text in by default. Thanks for taking the time to respond !!